# Mixing static referred and dynamic data in database

Tags: database, database-design, mongodb

I’m making an inventory for a game using nosql (mongo). I made some ItemType records (contains common data like icon, name, weight) and some ItemInstance records (representing specific items, referring to ItemType).

Now I have problem with mixing static and dynamic data in ItemType table. For example, health potion is id = 1 and user can dynamically add clothes types (which are item types too), then I will add more static item types (an apple). I need to have an ability to create Health Potion, so I have to hardcode it like `createInstance(1)` or use enum for this `createInstance(ItemType.Potion)`, but it will not work for an apple, since it’s inserted after dynamic types (id of apple will be any number, user can create any number of clothes item types).

How to deal with such thing? Allocate some ids as a constant pool looked up by enum, 1-1000 are static data, dynamic data are 1000-infinity? Divide collections to static and dynamic (and then somehow distinguish to which collection ItemInstance refers)? Any other common solution?

Comment: I haven't quiet grasped what makes any of these examples dynamic. Honestly, the way this is worded I'm not sure which ones you're saying are dynamic. Would you mind giving this an edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting limits on values for database identifiers can be problematic. Today, you think "surely 1000 static items will always be enough." But what happens when it isn't enough? Values 1-1000 and 1,000,000-2,000,000 become static items, which is a pain to remember (1,000 wasn't enough, and *surely* 1 million will be...).

Avoid hard-coding references to database identifiers if end users can add their own records, even if the system is responsible for generating new values.

Instead, consider that "static" and "dynamic" items are different entities from a data storage perspective. There is nothing wrong with storing them in different tables or collections. You can still map them to objects of the same type, if they behave the same in your application. Keeping static and dynamic items separate in storage allows you to tightly control identifiers for static items, which gives your application the freedom to hard-code those identifier values in the application.

I realize I just advised you to *not* do this, however, when you keep the curated items separate from the user-generated ones, then:

- You can be certain that Id values of static items do not clash with those created by users.
- You can eliminate the need to segment identifiers into static and dynamic sequences. You don't need to worry about the numbers of static items causing problems with database identifiers.
- Since the development team controls the identifiers for static items, it becomes safe to hard-code references to identifiers in the application. Alternately you can create an enum to represent those values.

While "items" as an abstraction in your application may behave the same, this does not mean storing them in the same place is desirable. I would advise you too keep static and dynamic items separate in storage because of how precisely you need to control identifiers for static items. You still have the option of mapping both sets of items to the same class in your application in case these two kinds of items share behavior.